# Deploying dynamic Angular App behind Cloudfront

Tags: angular, umbraco, amazon-cloudfront

So here is the use case :
We are building an SPA using angular wherein the content for the page shall be dynamically fetched from Umbraco headless CMS using API to complete the entire html.

I have seen links how to use static s3 bucket and put it behind CDN . But how do we manage with custom origin which renders dynamic pages (content+template in angular)  and put it behind CDN.

Since the Cloudfront  will generally cache by url and here the initial html template will have hardly any data , how do ensure that CDN caches the entire html after the merging of CMS data with the template. Having static site in s3 will be a bit too much since then we need to generate static html for all the pages and have a process to put it in s3 after every deployment

Would be helpful to know what is the best practise followed here ?

Please note we already use Cloudfront with CMS (Umbraco) but currently the entire page comes from the server (custom origin) hence it is a bit straightforward

Regards
Raghav

Comment: Can someone help here please